# Show that the linear map $T:P_3(\Bbb R)→\Bbb R^4, p↦(p(0),p(1),p′(0),p′(1))$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Show that the linear map

$$T:P_3(\Bbb R)→\Bbb R^4,\quad p↦(p(0),p(1),p′(0),p′(1))$$
is an isomorphism. 
what I did following shows it's not a isomorphism ,what's wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: Hint for a shorter solution: it's sufficient to show $T$ has trivial kernel (why?).  Now, if $p(0) = p'(0) = 0$ then $x^2 \mid p$ and if $p(1) = p'(1) = 0$ then $(x-1)^2 \mid p$.

Comment: You should explicitly state what $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is. It becomes clear if one looks at the attached photo, but a question should be asked in a form that its *essence* becomes transparent at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\in P_3(\mathbb R)$, then we have
$$\begin{align}&(1)\qquad p(0)=d
\\&(2)\qquad p(1)=a+b+c+d
\\&(3)\qquad p'(0)=c
\\&(4)\qquad p'(1)=3a+2b+c\end{align}$$

Therefore, your map $T$ sends
$$\begin{align}&(1)\qquad \color{red}{1\mapsto (1,1,0,0)}
\\&(2)\qquad x\mapsto (0,1,1,1)
\\&(3)\qquad x^2\mapsto (0,1,0,2)
\\&(4)\qquad x^3\mapsto (0,1,0,3)\end{align}$$
so you mapped $1$ incorrectly under $T$. You need to remember that $p'(x)$ loses the constant coefficient from $p(x)$.

---

But for your argument about mapping constant polynomials to $(0,0,0,0)$, this is false. $T$ maps constant polynomials to a scalar multiple of $(1,1,0,0)$. You should see that the matrix of $T$ relative to these standard bases is invertible, and therefore $T$ is an isomorphism (it is clearly linear).